# mysql error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

Im trying to create a table with this code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entries` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `atom_id` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `updated` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `inserted` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `atom_id` (`atom_id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `topics` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `status` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `hub` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `topic` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `lease` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `secret` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

but i got this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 12
```

I can't figure what's going on, any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the comma after `UNIQUE KEY 'atom_id' ('atom_id'),` in line 11

Answer (score 3):

```
UNIQUE KEY `atom_id` (`atom_id`),
                                ^
```

Try losing the ","